Is there a closed form solution for $ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{3x^2+1}dx$?
I forget where I came across this integral, but I have been intrigued by it.
$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{3x^2+1}dx$$
I have tried every technique I know to try to solve this and I came up short after every attempt.
I tried differentiating under the integral sign with the following set ups:
$$ I(t) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(tx)}{3x^2+1}dx$$
And,
$$ I(t) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{tx^2+1}dx$$
Both of which led to nowhere. I also tried the Laplace transform, series expansion, complex analysis, standard properties, and indefinite integration techniques, such as tangent half-angle sub and trig sub, but all came up short. If there is a closed form of this answer, I am wondering if there is an intuitive way of solving the integral. Any help would be appreciated.

Are you assuming that it has a simple value? If so, why?

What is your definition of a "closed form"?  $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\operatorname{arctan}(x)}{3x^2 + 1} ,\mathrm{d}x$ is a closed form, for a sufficiently broad definition of "closed form".

My definition of closed form would be the same as Wikipedia's. "In mathematics, an expression or equation is in closed form if it is formed with constants, variables and a finite set of basic functions connected by arithmetic operations (+, −, ×, /, and integer powers) and function composition." - Closed-form expression page

Sure, but note that your definition includes a finite list of basic functions.  What is your list?

If a closed form exists in terms of some specified list of functions, then Risch's algorithm should find it.  Most CASes implement some version of Risch, with a reasonably broad set of "basic" functions.  If a CAS is not finding a "nice" closed form, then it is very likely that such a thing does not exist.

@BenSpoolstra, what do you get when you do your first form of $I'(t)$ and then substitute $x^2= y$, followed by a partial fractions? It seems like a closed form should emerge out of that

I got  $\frac{\ln(t^2+1)-3\ln(4)}{2(t^2-3)}$ which when indefinitely integrated results in a poly logarithmic result which is seemingly the only “closed-form” answer to the problem I posed, so I’ll just accept that as the answer.

@BenSpoolstra There is a simple closed-form for your integral. Check out the comments in the second answer.

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x}{1+3x^2}dx\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\Big[\arctan\left(\sqrt{3}x\right)\arctan x\Big]_0^1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_0^1\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{3}x\right)}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{12\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_0^1\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{3}x\right)}{1+x^2}dx\\
F(a)&=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan\left(ax\right)}{1+x^2}dx\\
F^\prime(a)&=\int_0^1\frac{x}{(1+x^2)(1+a^2x^2)}dx\\
&=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+a^2}\right)}{2(1-a^2)}\\
J&=\frac{\pi^2}{12\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+a^2}\right)}{1-a^2}\\
&\overset{z=\frac{1-a}{1+a}}=\frac{\pi^2}{12\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}}^1\frac{\ln(1+z)}{z}dz+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}\underbrace{\int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}}^1\frac{\ln(1+z^2)}{z}dz}_{w=z^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{12\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\int_{\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}}^1\frac{\ln(1+z)}{z}dz+\frac{1}{8\sqrt{3}}\int_{\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2+\sqrt{3}}}^1\frac{\ln(1+w)}{w}dw\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{12\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}+1}\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)+\frac{1}{8\sqrt{3}}\left(\text{Li}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-2}{\sqrt{3}+2}\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{5\pi^2}{96\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\text{Li}_2\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)+\frac{1}{8\sqrt{3}}\text{Li}_2\left(4\sqrt{3}-7\right)}
\end{align}

You may be interested in this post. It gives a possible closed-form to the integral with the general denominator $nx^2+1$.

\begin{align}\int_0^{1}&\frac{\arctan x}{1+3x^2}{dx}
=\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac x{(3 x^2+1)(y^2x^2+1)}dy\ dx\\
 =&\int_0^1 \frac{\frac12\ln \frac {1+ (\sqrt3)^2}{1+y^2}}{(\sqrt3)^2-y^2}dy 
= \frac1{2\sqrt3}\Re \bigg[\text{Li}_2\bigg( \frac{\sqrt3 +1}{\sqrt3-i}\bigg)-\text{Li}_2\bigg( \frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt3+i}\bigg)\bigg]
\end{align}

We also have $$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)}{1+3x^2}dx = \frac{4\operatorname{Li_2}(x)+\ln^2(x)}{8\sqrt3}$$ where $x=2-\sqrt3.,$ Too bad they closed the question.

@TitoPiezasIII nice-looking result.

Thanks. I just realized I should have used a different variable for $\ln(x)$ instead of $x$. Sigh, force of habit.
